# Building package with 'build' does not exclude exclude-files (which setup.py does)

Tags: python, build, setuptools, setup.py, python-packaging

We're getting deprecation warnings when building with `python3 setup.py sdist` and after reading [Why you shouldn't invoke setup.py directly?](https://blog.ganssle.io/articles/2021/10/setup-py-deprecated.html) I see that the recomended alternative is to use [`build`](https://pypa-build.readthedocs.io/en/stable/).

| setup.py command | New command |
| --- | --- |
| setup.py sdist | python -m build (with build) |
| setup.py bdist_wheel |  |

When comparing the outputs I see that the deprecated `setup.py` excludes the **tests** directory (as specified with `packages=find_packages(exclude=['tests']),` while `python3 -m build` does not exclude this directory.

My understanding was that `build` still uses `setup.py`, albeit not directly, am I missing something? What is the correct way to avoid packaging the **tests** directory?

**Environment information**

- **OS**: Windows
- `python`: 3.10.10
- `pip`: 23.0.1
- `setuptools`: 65.5.0
- `build`: 0.10.0
- No `pyproject.toml` file in project

A minimal project behaves the same:

In my test sample project there is a `lib` directory with an empty `__init__.py` and `hello.py` with `print("hello")`, a `tests` directory with an empty `test_hello.py` file and the following `setup.py`:

```
from setuptools import find_packages, setup

setup(
  name="hello",
  version="0.1",
  author="myself",
  description="test package",
  packages=find_packages(exclude=["tests"]),
)
```

*Edit:* Opened issue on github https://github.com/pypa/setuptools/issues/3870

Comment: If that is true, then it might be a `setuptools` bug.

Comment: @sinoroc, I tried on two separate packages and saw the same behaviour. Do you have a different experience?

Comment: I have not tried to recreate the issue. -- What version of Python, *setuptools*, *build*, *pip*, operating system, etc.? Is there a `pyproject.toml` file? Add all these details to your question, not in the comments. -- Also some things changed recently-ish: https://github.com/pypa/setuptools/issues/3817 and https://github.com/pypa/distutils/issues/187

Comment: @sinoroc thanks for the input, I'll read up on the links. In the meantime I've added the environment information to the question.

Comment: BTW, I tired on WSL2 (Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS) with Python 3.8.10 and got similar results (tests is included in the egg-info although it's excluded in `setup.py`).

Answer (score 0):

After opening a [defect on github](https://github.com/pypa/setuptools/issues/3870) the problem was resolved by adding the following `pyproject.toml`:

```
[build-system]
build-backend = "setuptools.build_meta"
requires = ["setuptools==65.5"]
```